# jquery image over doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to apply an over effect on my photo slider.
I have the following code structure:

```
<div class="corpo_itens">
    <div class="foto-carousel">
        <div class="transparencia">
            <span>A Novilha Rebelde (The Sound of Mu)</span>
            <br /><br />
            Elisa Queiroz e Erly Vieira Jr., 18 min, Vitória (ES), 2005
        </div>
        <img src="img/foto_carousel1.jpg" alt="Nome da foto" />
        <div class="icon-foto"><img src="img/icon_video.png" alt="Vídeo" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is fadein and fadeout the "transparencia" div when the mouse rollover the image. This slider have different images and with following code it worked but it hide and show all divs at the same time...I have no clue how to solve it...

```
$('.foto-carousel').hover(
 function () {$('.transparencia').css({"display":"block"});}, 
 function () {$('.transparencia').css({"display":"none"});}
);
```

Comment: Are you trying for over effect or hover effect??

Comment: I think it should be hover effect...when you rollover the image it shows some content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide/show only the `.transparencia` inside the hovered `.foto-carousel` you'll have to specify context, like

```
$('.foto-carousel').hover(
    function () {$('.transparencia', this).css({"display":"block"});}, 
    function () {$('.transparencia', this).css({"display":"none"});}
);
```

Comment: Hey Musa, thanks for your help, it work's like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".corpo_itens img").onmouseover(function(){
  $(this).parent().children(".transparencia").fadeIn(100);
});
$(".corpo_itens img").onmouseout(function(){
  $(this).parent().children(".transparencia").fadeOut(100);
});
```

Or something like this.